# Nuxt.js / Node.js Nginx requests per second

Tags: node.js, linux, performance, nginx, nuxt.js

I'm trying to prepare a CentOS server to run Nuxt.js (Node.js) application via Nginx reverse proxy.

First, I fire up a simple test server that returns an HTTP 200 response with the text "ok". It easily handles ~10.000 requests/second with ~10ms of mean latency.

Then, when I switch to the hello-world NUXT example app (npx create-nuxt-app) and I run weighttp http benchmarking tool to run the following command:

```
weighttp -n 10000 -t 4 -c 100 localhost:3000
```

The results are as follows:

```
starting benchmark...
spawning thread #1: 25 concurrent requests, 2500 total requests
spawning thread #2: 25 concurrent requests, 2500 total requests
spawning thread #3: 25 concurrent requests, 2500 total requests
spawning thread #4: 25 concurrent requests, 2500 total requests
progress:  10% done
progress:  20% done
progress:  30% done
progress:  40% done
progress:  50% done
progress:  60% done
progress:  70% done
progress:  80% done
progress:  90% done
progress: 100% done

finished in 9 sec, 416 millisec and 115 microsec, 1062 req/s, 6424 kbyte/s
requests: 10000 total, 10000 started, 10000 done, 10000 succeeded, 0 failed, 
0 errored
status codes: 10000 2xx, 0 3xx, 0 4xx, 0 5xx
traffic: 61950000 bytes total, 2000000 bytes http, 59950000 bytes data
```

As You can see it won't climb over 1062 req/s. Sometimes I can reach something like ~1700 req/s if I ramp up the concurrency param, but no more than that.

I'm expecting a simple hello world example app to run at least ~10.000 req/s without a high delay or latency on this machine.

I've tried checking file limits, open connection limits, Nginx workers, etc but couldn't find the root cause, so I'm really looking forward to any ideas on where to at least start searching for the root cause.

I can provide any logs or any other additional info if needed.

Comment: its totally fine result, your expectations is wrong. You cant compare serving static file via nginx with ssr with virtual dom. And even if its hello world nuxt have a lot of features enabled by default

Comment: for example if u disable all unused staff for hello-world ( available in nuxt-edge) - you will get something like 2k

Comment: and if u use cache ( like nuxt-ssr-cache) to be comparable with nginx you will get something like 8-9k

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).